# Normalizing line endings in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

When I open a cs file with inconsistent line endings, Visual Studio 2019 doesn't pop up **Inconsistent Line Endings** dialog box anymore. **Check for consistent line endings on load** is also marked in **Options/Documents** so there's no reason for not showing up. I used to normalize line endings with the help of the dialog box but for some unknown reasons it won't pop up anymore and I don't know how to force normalizing in VS. Any help would be appreciated.

**Workaround:** For now the only way I came up with is to force normalize using **Edit/Advanced/Set Newlines/CRLF.** This causes VS to replace all LF with CRLF.

Comment: What I do -- 1a. Add the file in a dummy git repository which checks EOF according to .gitconfig 1b. Open it in Notepad++ and apply the EOF or 2a. Export current VS settings 2b. Reset all settings and check if VS reports any EOF pop up.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but, resetting settings didn't solve the problem.
And about your solution with Notepad++: yes I do have alternatives like yours, however, I prefer doing all the work within VS.

Comment: [Line Ending Unifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakubBielawa.LineEndingsUnifier) perhaps?